# tkinter images on canvas disappears

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to place copies of "master" image, which name i choose from tk.Listbox, on canvas. Full program code is so big to place here, so i put parts of this.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import Tkinter as tk
import dircache
import copy

def callback(event):
    label.master_image=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path))
    label.configure(image=label.master_image)


def apply():
    canvas.copy_image=copy.copy(label.master_image)
    canvas.create_image(10,10,canvas.copy_image)


root=tk.Tk()

frame=tk.Frame(master=root)
canvas=tk.Canvas(master=frame)

listbox=tk.Listbox(master=frame)
listbox.insert(tk.END, *dircache.listdir('./images'))
listbox.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', callback)

label=tk.Label(master=frame)

button=tk.Button(master=frame, text='Apply', command=apply)

canvas.pack()
frame.pack()
listbox.pack()
label.pack()
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

But when i just click on another menu point(not on "Apply" button), that means that `label.master_image` changes, image on canvas disappears.

P.S. `label.master_image` used for preview it on label before apply changes on canvas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep reference to the image. `copy.copy` is not necessary.

**`canvas.copy_image = label.master_image`**

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import Tkinter as tk
import os

def callback(event):
    idx, = listbox.curselection()
    path = os.path.join('images', listbox.get(idx))
    label.master_image=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path))
    label.configure(image=label.master_image)


def apply():
    canvas.copy_image = label.master_image
    canvas.create_image(10,10, image=canvas.copy_image)


root=tk.Tk()

frame=tk.Frame(master=root)
canvas=tk.Canvas(master=frame)

listbox=tk.Listbox(master=frame)
listbox.insert(tk.END, *os.listdir('images'))
listbox.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', callback)

label=tk.Label(master=frame)

button=tk.Button(master=frame, text='Apply', command=apply)

canvas.pack()
frame.pack()
listbox.pack()
label.pack()
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Yes, thanks, it works, but i don't see such global difference between them.

Comment: Grep `canvas.copy_image *=` or `del *canvas.copy_image` for you entire code.

Comment: I removed `copy.copy`, and it works. Maybe, there was an error elsewhere.